# What is the name of the following algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

I am  using the following algorithm to solve an optimization problem I have. I was wondering if there is a proper name for this algorithm in the literature.

Let $f(x)$ be my objective function.

I guess some $x_0$ and see have it performs.

Next, I **randomly** generate around $x_0$, some $\{x_k \}$ for $k \in [1:K]$  and see how the compare to $x_0$.  If I find  $x_n$ that perform better than $x_0$.
I perform the same procedure again with $x_n$.

I am only starting to learn about algorithms and would be grateful if you point me to the name and some reference on similar algorithms

Comment: I don't recall seeing a precise name for the particular variant you have, but it's a type of [Random Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_search) - essentially a Local Search where you select elements from the neighbourhood at random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a form of [local search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_search_%28optimization%29).  It is similar to [hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing).  It's also reminiscent of [stochastic hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_hill_climbing), as @Juho suggests.

Comment: I think this is actually [stochastic hill climbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_hill_climbing), if you want to find a more exact name.